# Codigo javascript com erro e nao consigo achar

Tags: javascript

Eu n entendo muito de javascript, ent dei uma pesquisada na net e achei um codigo de formulario dinamico, só que apresenta esse erro http://prntscr.com/mp80qt, eu não faço ideia do que pode ser.

```
$(function(){
  $("#estados").change(function(){
    var uf = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "exibe_cidade.php?uf="+uf,
      dataType:"text",
      success: function(res){
        $("#cidades").children(".cidades").remove();
        $("#cidades").append(res);

      }
    });
  });
});
```

ele interage com esse codigo php que era pra puxar uma lista de cidade

```
<?php

require_once "func/conn.php";

$uf = $_GET['uf'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_cidade WHERE uf = ? ORDER BY nome';
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stm->bindValue(1, $uf);
$stm->execute();
$lista = $stm->fetchAll();
for($i=0;$i<count($lista);$i++){ 
    $id = $lista[$i]['id'];
    $nome = $lista[$i]['nome'];

    echo '<option value="'.$id.'" class="cidades">'.$nome.'</option>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Utilize o *jQuery* https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta adicionar a biblioteca [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), você pode usar esse CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Vlw cara, me ajudou muito, fiquei muito tempo quebrando a cabeça com isso haha, obrigado

Comment: Se minha resposta resolveu seu problema, pode aceitar clicando no ✓ do lado da resposta

Comment: Me desculpe incomodar novamente, mais eu queria que o codigo removesse 2 elemento de uma vez, só que não quer funcionar, eu adicionei uma linha idêntica com a de cima assim $("#cidades").children(".cidades").remove(); $("#universidades").children(".universidades").remove(); mais n quer funcionar, saberia me informar oq falta?

Comment: Sem o HTML é complicado responder, abra uma nova pergunta e adicione o jQuery e HTML. Evite fazer muitas perguntas num único post